# Folded Overload Protection in Linear regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, protection, linear

Can someone please explain how Q1 is able to protect from overload this linear circuit?

[image]

Please see below for a simpler schematic of the above[image]:

Comment: If the voltage at Vout gets too low (i.e. if the voltage regulator starts providing too much current), then Q1 will turn off. This will result in current flowing through D8 into the voltage control, making it think that the output voltage is too high, causing it to then try to reduce the output voltage. This is a comment because I'm not sure how it then turns off the overload protection once the fault condition is removed.

Comment: @BeB00 If Vout gets too low, does it not mean that the base voltage of Q2 is low? I can see your point that D8 would be forward-biased if the output voltage is low, but I am confused that the output low voltage turns off Q2.

Comment: Correct, the base voltage of Q1 is low, so it turns off. Q2 does not turn off, it turns on more, because of the current from D8. This causes Q3 and Q4 to turn on less, which lowers the output voltage.

Comment: @BeB00 Thank you so much. So if the protection is not active, Q1 would be ON (active region or saturation?) and D8 would be OFF?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: @chami Sometimes, it just helps a lot to [redraw things](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X9xhZ.png).

Comment: I don't see Q1 doing any foldback with Vce1= saturated with a Thevenin Equiv. bias of 2.1V with less than 5k  to base.  It seems to rely on leakage current in Q4 with no load to start up. weird.  https://tinyurl.com/ycgns8on

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 No, it doesn't depend upon Q4 leakage.

Comment: @Tony Stewart EE75 During the start-up, Q1 is not in cut-off?

Comment: Q1 is off on start and R8+D8 saturates Q2

Comment: Then with Early leakage on Q4 and no load, it starts up and then Q1 is saturated.. I guess the R3 C3 saturates Q1 so it starts up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the re-drawn schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZVgkX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, the unregulated DC has a power output for the rest of the circuit, but also includes a small pulse that occurs once per full cycle. This pulse attempts to momentarily (through \$C_3\$) pull up on the base of \$Q_1\$, which if successful continually discharges \$C_4\$, keeping \$D_8\$ from conducting (through \$R_6\$) and pulling up on the base of \$Q_2\$ and thereby shutting down the DC output voltage.

Separately, \$R_2\$ measures the output voltage (implicitly, by how that voltage biases \$Q_1\$.) If there is insufficient output voltage (which there will be at first) then the pulsing via \$C_3\$ will be insufficient and \$Q_1\$ will remain off thereby allowing \$R_6\$, via \$D_8\$, to hold \$Q_2\$ active and keep the output voltage off.

Also, \$C_6\$ will initially be discharged and thereby keep the Darlington **off** during initial power-up. So there will be a short time (determined approximately by \$\tau=R_9\cdot C_6\$) during power-up where the DC output voltage is held **off**.

There's a lot that's ugly about the circuit. For the DC output to remain shut-off (after the initial startup-period where it is held **off** anyway by \$C_6\$) due to some perceived too-high load current, the DC output voltage must reach a certain low voltage value long enough so that the pulse-per-cycle input *also* fails to sufficiently pull up on \$Q_1\$'s base enough to discharge \$C_4\$ each cycle. But that's determined by the magnitude of the combination of \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ (which are supplying current for part of the cycle) as well as the voltage drops through \$R_9\$, \$R_8\$, the \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$ of \$Q_3\$ and \$Q_4\$, and resistors \$R_{11}\$ and \$R_{13}\$. It also depends on the biasing pair value choices for \$R_2\$ and \$R_5\$, of course. And it also depends on the values of \$\beta\$ for \$Q_3\$ and \$Q_4\$ for any particular temperature and current, as well.

It's not under good management, in short.

In general, as the load current increases, there will be increased ripple due to loading on \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$. This ripple makes its way through \$R_8\$, \$R_9\$, \$Q_3\$, resistors \$R_{11}\$ and \$R_{13}\$, and \$Q_4\$ to yield (at some point) ripple at DC out. The ripple at DC out must then reach a point where the biasing pair of \$R_2\$ and \$R_5\$ no longer allow \$Q_1\$ (with pulsing input, once per cycle, via \$C_3\$) to reset (discharge) \$C_4\$. When that no longer happens, then \$R_6\$ and \$D_8\$ conspire to pull up on the base of \$Q_2\$, thereby shutting down the DC output.

When the load on the circuit is returned to a low enough value, then \$C_1\$, \$C_2\$ and eventually also \$C_7\$ will charge back up sufficiently that the biasing pair, \$R_2\$ and \$R_5\$, allow the pulses through \$C_3\$ to periodically (once again) discharge \$C_4\$ so that \$D_8\$ no longer keeps \$Q_2\$ fully **on**, thereby allowing \$Q_2\$ to perform in analog fashion to keep the DC output voltage at its regulated value.

So long as \$Q_1\$ can keep discharging \$C_4\$, \$D_8\$ is blocked and \$Q_2\$ performs its analog regulation function via the potentiometer setting. But the moment that \$Q_1\$ can no longer perform that function, for whatever reason, then \$Q_2\$ is pulled up and held active thereby pulling down on the base of \$Q_3\$ and yanking the output close to ground.

I don't like it. Not one bit. It's not well-managed. I'd use a serious current-foldback circuit followed by an over-voltage crowbar. (*Back in the day* tech.) But this is what it is.